# Passing a custom class/style to a styled-component in Gatsby (React)

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styled-components

I've created the following styled-component for my gatsby project.

```
import React from "react"
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'


const Button = styled.div`
    background-color: #4E58F5;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease;

  ${props => props.primary && css`
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: red;
  `}
`;

export default props => (
    <Button>{props.buttonText}</Button>
)
```

I've not found the examples in the documentation to be clear or consistent enough to understand how I should be passing in the "primary" option to my components.

I'm trying to do the following, on my `index.js` page.  The Button renders, but the primary word has no effect.  What am I missing here?

```
<Button primary buttonText="Submit" />
```

Comment: Have you looked at [styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/)?

Comment: Yes - there's no clear example that's exactly what I want.  I figured it out from the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you're exporting, does not recognize the `primary` property, and thus cannot pass it on to the Button element. You can fix this either by exporting the styled component itself, or by passing unrecognized props to the Button.

```
const Button = styled.div`
  [...]
`;

export default Button;
```

OR

```
export default ({buttonText, ...props})=>(
  <Button {...props}>{buttonText}</Button>
);
```

Comment: Thanks!  So if I went with the first option, where would the following code go?

```export default props => (
    <Button>{props.buttonText}</Button>
)``` - i.e. where is `buttonText` and the structure of the button handled?

Comment: No, in the first example, the file ends with the `export default Button`-line, you'd have to change your call-sites to be something like `<Button primary>Submit</Button>`. In the second example, you can keep calling it as `<Button primary buttonText='submit'/>`, but you'd have to change the function you're exporting.